# Replace content on click with addEventListener JS

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I have a sub-menu that becomes visible when I click on a specific part using addEventListener, I also have another function that closes that same sub-menu when clicked in one of the sub-menus elements, however, I want to be able to change the content of the very first div, with the contents of the div that was clicked in the sub-menu.
Example. There is an Ethereum Icon, when clicked on the icon, the sub-menu appears, after clicking on another Crypto Icon, the very first Ethereum needs to be replaced with what was clicked. How would I do that?
P.S I am only showing the JS code since there is a lot of HTML, if it is needed I will provide it.

```
const toggle = document.querySelector(".row-left");
const hide = document.querySelector(".hidden");
const blur = document.querySelector(".main-container");
const button = document.querySelector(".close");
const crypto = document.querySelectorAll(".crypto-list");
const toggle2 = document.querySelector(".lefty");

let menuOpen = false;
const closeModal = function toggle() {
  if (!menuOpen) {
    hide.classList.remove("hidden");
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    hide.classList.add("hidden");

    menuOpen = false;
  }
};

toggle.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

toggle2.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

button.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

for (let i = 0; i < crypto.length; i++)
  crypto[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!menuOpen) {
      hide.classList.remove("hidden");
      menuOpen = true;
    } else {
      hide.classList.add("hidden");
      menuOpen = false;
    }
  });
```

Sub-menu which will appear.

```
    <div class="list">
          <div class="crypto-list">
            <div class="list-image">
              <img src="index.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="crypto-text">
              <h5>ETH</h5>
              <p>Ether</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="crypto-list">
            <div class="list-image">
              <img src="index.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="crypto-text">
              <h5>ETH</h5>
              <p>Ether</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="crypto-list">
            <div class="list-image">
              <img src="index.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="crypto-text">
              <h5>ETH</h5>
              <p>Ether</p>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

This divs content needs to be changed, essentially only the image and the h3 text

```
<div class="row-left">
                <img src="index.png" alt="" />
                <div class="row-left-text">
                  <p>Swap From:</p>
                  <h3>ETH</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="down-arrow">
                  <img src="arrow1-1.png" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Share menu/ sub-menu HTML. With what you have tried upto

Comment: I just edited those parts in, hope those help